# What is the syntax for setting up and calling a private member function in A from B using a function pointer?

Tags: c++, callback, function-pointers

I'm trying to create a callback function that Foo can call to Bar. I run into "Run-Time Check Failure #0". I've done some research about this but it hasn't clicked for me, hence my I'm posting this question.

I first ran into this problem trying to set up a trigger gameplay system for my hobbyproject in UE4, I've just simplified the code to post it here.

Foo class:

```
#pragma once

class Bar;

class Foo
{
public:

    Foo(Bar* bar);
    ~Foo(){}    

private:

    void TestCB();

};
```

cpp:

```
#include "Foo.h"

#include <iostream>

#include "Bar.h"

Foo::Foo(Bar* bar)
{
    bar->SetUpCallback(this, &Foo::TestCB);
}

void Foo::TestCB()
{
    std::cout << "It Actually Works!";
}
```

Bar class:

```
#pragma once

class Foo;

class Bar
{
public:

    typedef void (Foo::*VoidFuncPtrNoParams)(void);

    Bar() {}
    ~Bar() {}

    void SetUpCallback(Foo* owner, VoidFuncPtrNoParams callback);
    void CallCB();

private:

    Foo* CBOwner;
    VoidFuncPtrNoParams CBToCall;
};
```

cpp:

```
#include "Bar.h"

#include "Foo.h"

void Bar::SetUpCallback(Foo* owner, VoidFuncPtrNoParams callback)
{
    CBOwner = owner;
    CBToCall = callback;
}

void Bar::CallCB()
{
    (CBOwner->* (CBToCall))();
}
```

main:

```
#include "Foo.h"
#include "Bar.h"

int main()
{
    Bar* bar = new Bar();
    Foo* foo = new Foo(bar);
    bar->CallCB();

    delete bar;
    bar = nullptr;
    delete foo;
    foo = nullptr;

    return 0;
}
```

I'm obviously expecting it to output "It Actually Works!", however, it runs into the runtime error trying to exit the Foo's constructor.

Comment: @steve Forgot to add the .h files, no idea what I was thinking as they're extremely crucial to my question, sorry, but they're included now.

Comment: @PeteBecker Hey, I'm clumsy and forgot the header files even though they're extremely crucial to my question, sorry, theyre included now.

Comment: The sample code that's posted in the question compiles without any errors, and runs without any errors, printing "It Actually Works!". There's nothing obviously wrong with the shown code. Therefore, your problem is somewhere else, and has nothing to do with anything that's shown here. Voting to close as "unable to reproduce". Take what you've posted here, and set it aside, then keep adding small bits of code from your real program until it no longer works. At which point you've found your bug.

Comment: Passing an object to a constructor and changing that passed in object is questionable and will surprise a lot of developers. A better approach is to first construct the object and then set the callback. In addition this looks pretty much like a callable object in disguise, why not use that. Also the code is very tightly coupled.

Comment: @steve I absolutely agree with that the constructor set up is questionable at best, it was just hastely done to provide a question with as little code as possible. I must say I've never come across a callable object, I must do some research on it.